# SystemVerilog Constraint, Fixing value every nth iteration

Tags: system-verilog

```
class Base
 rand bit b;
// constraint c1 { every 5th randomization should have b =0;}
endclass
```

I know I can make a static count variable and update that count variable and then, in constraint I can check if count%5 is zero, then make b=0, but is there a better way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: It was just asked in an interview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to make count static, just non-random.

```
class Base;
  rand bit b;
  int count;
  constraint c1 { count%5 -> b==0;}
  function post_randomize();
    count++;
  endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: Thanks @dave_59. Can you please let me know how count being non-static member will be shared by all the instances of the class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't specify in your original question if you were planning to randomize one object repeatedly, or create many objects randomizing them once. Yes for the latter, the count would need to be static.

Answer (score -1):

If you know the upper limit of `b`, then you can write a constraint like follow.

```
constraint abc 
{
  b dist {0:=20, 1:=80}
}
```

This will make weight of `0` to `20` and, weight of `1` to `80`. So in this way, 0 will occur once in every 5 randomization.

Comment: That is not correct. Having a 1 in 5 probability is not the same thing as once in every 5 occurrences,

Comment: So you mean to say, that it's not guaranteed that tool will generate 0 once in every 5 randomization with the above constraint?

Comment: Correct. Probability is not a guarantee.